# Why doesn't this snippet work in the node repl?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started playing with ES6 and Node, experimenting with the new features in a node repl:

```
{
  const str = 'Alice';
  let arr = [];

  for (let c of str) {
    arr.push(c);
  }

  arr;
}
```

Errors thrown:

```
const str = 'Alice';
      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  arr;
ReferenceError: arr is not defined
```

I couldn't figure out what I did wrong (thinking maybe the block statement doesn't work that way), so I turned to the Chrome console to confirm. The snippet works fine. So why it doesn't work in the node repl (v7.8.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh, the problem is how you have defined your code in `{...}`. It should work as expected, as you have said that it works in chrome's dev console. ( *note, what you did is somewhat unusual use of the [destructuring assignment](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-destructuring-assignment) but ... it's a nice thing to know why it doesn't work in repl!* )

Apparently repl stops creating when you're using the ending curly brace, the `}`, thus executing the content defined within `{` and `}`. Let add your code step by step in repl and you will get an error when you add the `}` of your for-loop:

```
> {
... const str = 'Alice';
... let arr = [];
... for (let c of str) {
..... arr.push(c);
..... }
const str = 'Alice';
      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

So the code that the parser receives is

```
{
  const str = 'Alice';
  let arr = [];

  for (let c of str) {
    arr.push(c);
  }
```

Which is of course not correct. If you re-write the code a bit, without having an ending `}` in the scope, then it works! Try this code

```
{
  const str = 'Alice';
  let arr = [];
  for (let c of str) arr.push(c);
  arr;
}
```

image:

[image]

This works. The problem may lie at how node repl treats the {} stuff.

### UPDATE

*I was intrigued, so checked this further.* The problem is that repl starts to evaluate your statement once you have pressed  after placing a `}` character. I have checked this and if you do the following:

```
{
    const a = 'Alice';
    let arr = [];
    for (let c of a) {
        arr.push(c);
    } arr; }
```

Please note the use of two `}` in one line. You will get an answer;

```
> {
...     const a = 'Alice';
...     let arr = [];
...     for (let c of a) {
.....         arr.push(c);
.....     } arr; }
[ 'A', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'e' ]
```

Congratulations. You have discovered a bug in node repl.